# How can I avoid that my wife’s iPad sounds an alarm every time I add an event to a shared calendar in iCal?

Tags: ipad, icloud, calendar, notifications, ical

I share my work calendar on iCal with my wife (synced with iCloud). Every time I add an event to that calendar, my wife’s iPad plays a sound. Because I live in Europe but work for a company in the US, this often happens in the middle of the night for us, and the pings wake her up.

Is there a way to disable these sound notifications on her iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in the **Notifications** settings.

### How to adjust notifications for iOS Calendar

On the iPad:

- Go to **Settings**
- Select **Notifications**
- Select **Calendar**
- Select **Shared Calendar Changes**
- Select **Sounds**
- Select **None**

One can also adjust several other types of notifications as well or even completely disable notifications for the Calendar app.

Another setting to look at is **Do Not Disturb**
This can be set manually or on a schedule.

From the settings:

> When Do Not Disturb is enabled, a moon icon will appear in the status bar and incoming FaceTime calls and alerts will be silenced.

Comment: Glad it helped!!